# I need to get the output file of a vcxproj programatically using c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, scripting, vcxproj

I know that I can look into properties,TargetPath, TargetDir, TargetFileName, by right clicking on a project and checking out it's properties but I need to do this programatically. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get such properties (using the selected startup project as an example) starting with the following code:

```
Project startupProject = DTE.Solution.Item(((DTE.Solution.SolutionBuild as SolutionBuild2).StartupProjects as object[])[0]);
Properties p = startupProject.ConfigurationManager.ActiveConfiguration.Properties;
```

Comment: what module do I include to access the Project and Properties class?

Comment: EnvDTE.dll - it's a standard module for any Visual Studio extension. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.project.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.properties.aspx

Comment: Sergey Vlasov this method seems to work great until I get this recurring error: A first chance exception of type Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException' occurred in Microsoft.Build.dll